# How to get more values from Access c#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I want to select a sentence from the database, but i don't know how to write the code. I will search for a number by reading lines from the textbox.

```
                for (int i = 0; i < lines.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
                {
                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    string query1 = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SolozinnenTabel WHERE Faciliteitnummer = " + lines[i] + " AND Paragraaf LIKE '" + AlineaKinderenNaam + "%' ORDER BY rnd(ID)";
                    command.CommandText = query1;
                    OleDbDataReader reader1 = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader1.Read()) {
                        RichAccoText.Text = RichAccoText.Text + reader1["Zin"].ToString();
                        RichFacilityText.Lines = RichFacilityText.Lines.Where(line => line != lines[i]).ToArray();

                    }
                }
```

This code works but I only can search for one line and search them in the textbox. So I want something like this:

string query1 = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CombizinnenTabel WHERE (Faciliteitnummer1= " + lines[a] + " AND Faciliteitnummer2= " + lines[a] + ") AND Paragraaf LIKE '" + AlineaAccommodatieNaam + "%' ORDER BY rnd(ID)";

lines[a] = 80, but I want to search:

If Faciliteitnummer1 = lines[80] en Faciliteitnummer2 = lines[48]and Faciliteitnummer3 = lines[18], then select this sentence.....

If (Faciliteitnummer1 = lines[80] en Faciliteitnummer2 = lines[10]and Faciliteitnummer3 = lines[0], then select this sentence....

Comment: Have a look at the SQL operator IN   http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-IN.asp